# Read CSV file and write function result in another one

Tags: python, csv

I have a CSV file on which one I would like to make a process and save the result to an output.csv file.

This is my customer.csv file :

```
id, email, first_name, last_name, institution, creation_date, modification_date, country
1;tar.ber@test.eu;tar;ber;EDTG,TGD;;;
2;val.dzz@test.eu;var;dzz;Test with , inside;;;
...
```

Some institution field have `,` inside. So I would like to set `" "` around each institution field.

```
#Input data
1;tar.ber@test.eu;tar;ber;EDTG,TGD;;;
2;val.dzz@test.eu;var;dzz;Test with , inside;;;

#Output data
1;tar.ber@test.eu;tar;ber;"EDTG,TGD";;;
2;val.dzz@test.eu;var;dzz;"Test with , inside";;;
```

This is my code :

```
import csv
import re

with open('customer.csv', 'r') as csvFile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvFile, delimiter=";")
    writer = csv.writer(open("output.csv", 'w'))
    for row in reader:
        id = row[0]
        email= row[1]
        first_name = row[2] 
        last_name = row[3] 
        institution = row[4]
        modification_date = row[5]
        country = row[6] 
        creation_date = row[7]
        writer.writerow(id+';'+email+';'+first_name+';'+last_name+';"'+institution+'";'+modification_date+';'+country+';'+creation_date)
```

In my Terminal it gives me :

```
1;tar.ber@test.eu;tar;ber;"EDTG,TGD";;;
2;val.dzz@test.eu;var;dzz;"Test with , inside";;;
```

But in my output.csv file, I get :

```
1,;,t,a,r,.,b,e,r,@,t,e,s,t,.,e,u,;,t,a,r,;,b,e,r,;,"""",E,D,T,G,,T,G,D,"""",;,;,;
```

I don't understand why ?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of creating a string to pass to `writer.writerow` you should create a list of strings.

```py
        writer.writerow([id, email, first_name, last_name, institution, modification_date, country, creation_date])
```

Note then that row is already what you want, so you can simplify this to

```py
import csv
import re

with open('customer.csv', 'r') as csvFile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvFile, delimiter=";")
    writer = csv.writer(open("output.csv", 'w'), delimiter=";", quoting=QUOTE_NONNUMERIC)
    for row in reader:
        writer.writerow(row)
```

Also, you should add the right delimiter to the writer as well.

Finally, I think the csv module will handle the quoting correctly. That is, if the delimiter is ',' it would quote a ',' within the data, otherwise it will not. So according to csv specification, adding quotes around the institution with the ',' inside would be wrong.

If you need the quotes nontheless, you can use the `quoting` keyword argument of the csv library. These are the constants that it supports. https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.QUOTE_ALL. Unfortunately, it does not support quoting only the specific fields that you want (unless you change the delimiter to ','), but you can quote all fields, or all non-numeric fields.

To explain the behavior that you are seeing: it looks like `writerow` will iterate over whatever it is given, and thus it iterated on the string that you constructed and interpreted each character as a single field, thus adding ',' between each.

Comment: But it's not my question. I would like to set between `" "` institution field at each row and write the result to an output.csv file. Your example let to don't have comma at each character, but don't make the expected result.

Comment: See my edit about the `quoting` feature. I misunderstood your question the first time.

Comment: Ok, to make simple, I would like to quote all institutions, with or not comma inside.

Comment: It gives me `"1";"tar.ber@test.eu";"tar";"ber";"EDTG,TGD";"";"";""` but `"1"` is an integer not a charvar so `QUOTE_ALL` is not good to my mind.

Comment: Yep. That's what QUOTE_ALL does. You can use `QUOTE_NONNUMERIC` if you want to keep integers.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186850/discussion-between-bimmlerd-and-essex).

Answer (score 0):

The primary problem is you need to pass `writer.writerow()`a sequence of items, not a string. To get the delimiters you want, you need to specify `delimiter=";"` when creating the `csv.writer` as well as the `csv.reader` objects. There were a few other issues, like how you're `open()` the csv files, one should always specify `newline=''` to make sure newlines get handled correctly.

I also added a line to copy the header line to the output file. Anyway, this is what `output.csv` contains after running it:

```
id, email, first_name, last_name, institution, creation_date, modification_date, country
1;tar.ber@test.eu;tar;ber;EDTG,TGD;;;
2;val.dzz@test.eu;var;dzz;Test with , inside;;;
```

And here's your code with modifications:

```
import csv

with open('customer.csv', 'r', newline='') as csvFile, \
     open("output.csv", 'w', newline='') as outFile:
        reader = csv.reader(csvFile, delimiter=";")
        writer = csv.writer(outFile, delimiter=";")

        writer.writerow(next(reader))  # Copy header row.
        for row in reader:
            id, email, first_name, last_name, institution = row[0:5]
            modification_date, country, creation_date = row[5:8]
            writer.writerow([id, email, first_name, last_name, institution,
                             modification_date, country, creation_date])
```